# Middleware to check if ajax request is authenticated is not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, middleware

I am trying to handle ajax request that were initiated from idle/expired session(maybe the page was left open and the session got expired). I wrote the below middleware but it's not working as expected:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AjaxSessionCheck
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!\Auth::check())
        {
            if($request->ajax())
            {
                return response()->json(['Session_error'=>'Session Expired'], 401);
                //throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

To check if this worked i logged into the same page that contains the form from two separate tabs and then logged out from one of the tab, making the session invalid on the other tab as well. Then i initiated an ajax request(user clicks a delete button).

Any help to the right direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add your logout endpoint and can you confirm that is working as expected?

Comment: @AlexHarris: Hi Haris, can you please clarify a bit on your comment? Like what should i do to follow your instruction? I am new to laravel.

Comment: Can we see the code that makes the session invalid?

Comment: @AlexHarris: The code does not make the session invalid. Probably i could not make my problem clear enough. The thing is i want to check, at server side, that whether an ajax request is coming from an authenticated/valid session. If not, i want to send a specific JSON response. I found incidentally that my ajax call is failing(As i left the page open till session expires and then clicked the button that initiates an ajax request). The same ajax call works fine as long as the session is valid. So i thought to add this middleware that i wrote to handle such cases. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

for better coverage use `if ($request->isJson() || $request->wantsJson()) {`

Comment: Tried, but no luck :(